# Is it possible to deploy a high available file service with two file servers using a shared virtual hard disk and DFS with Windows Server 2019?

Tags: high-availability, windows-server-2019, dfs, file-server

In my infrastructure, I have two servers with Windows Server 2019 and Hyper-V installed. A SAN is directly connected to both servers via FC. The SAN provides three volumes to both servers: a volume for the quorum, a volume for VMs and a volume for data.

I plan to deploy a file service that is as much high available as my given infrastructure can go. Therefore - as I have two nodes - I want to deploy two file servers. This way, I can tolerate the failure of one whole server (host) or a failure of one virtual file server. With just one virtual file server (with HA enabled), I would just tolerate the failure of one host, but not a failure of the VM itsself.

I plan to use the data volume of my SAN to deploy a shared virtual hard disk, that both virtual file servers will use to provide the file shares.

Further more, I want that the users don't have to care which file server they access to access their files. `\\FileSrv1\Data\README.md` should be the same as `\\FileSrv2\Data\README.md`, but users should be able to access it like `\\FS\Data\README.md`. As far as I know, this is a typical use case for DFS. But I don't want two file servers that replicate their data, as I have a shared storage.

So my question is, can I use both - a shared storage for virtual file servers AND DFS to abstract the file access - in my scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I do not necessarily need DFS in my scenario. The guest failover cluster of the file servers already provides an abstraction layer to access the files, so I just called the clustered role `fs`. In conclusion, files can always be accessed by `\\FS\...` no matter which of the file servers is active.

Comment: a DFS is always a good solution on a longterm service, since you can always use the same name even if you change the server behind of.

Comment: To be clear, DFS "Namespace" is always good, whether or not you use DFS "Replication" (which isn't always good.) Two different features in the DFS portfolio.

Comment: @mfinni Agreed. But as long as I stick to the file server clustering technology, even my approach will survive future migrations. I _just_ have to add the shared virtual hard disk to one or more new virtual file servers and add this/these new file servers to the already exisiting cluster. After that, I can remove the old ones. Might be a migration with no downtime, while keeping all existing paths. Just leaving that idea here, as I might come back in 5 years or so ;-)